# Best Way to develope android applications?

Tags: android

This is my first post here.i need to know which is the best way to do android application..
I have already working with unity3d for games.now i need to develope some applications in this platform.

i have tried with "ECLIPSE" with ADT plugin.Its taking too much of time to open and install applications in EMULATOR.i'm sitting more than two hours behind my system.still the emulator is not opening,thats why am getting worry about this and asking any other solution for this??

if you know means help me guys...

Thanks for advance.

Comment: The best way is to sit down and start writing some code :)

Comment: What is your system configuration (memory, cpu, OS)? Two hours for emulator startup is much too long.

Comment: hurrah....just now am getting my layouts in emulator...using windows7,320 gb memory

Comment: @olegas, IMHO is the open source ???

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way IMHO, it is developing on the real device. But anyway, emulator is needed to perform some checking in different environment (API level, screen density).